PhD in Economics, Finance, Mathematics, and/or Statistics?
Moderator Bob Jansen unilaterally closed PhD in Economics, Finance, Mathematics, and/or Statistics? as "seeking career advice". But I intended this to be a question on education? How can I improve it? 

This question is unsalvageable as 

Getting a PhD is part of a career, hence a question about getting a specific PhD is career advice;
The answer is primarily opinion based.

Please read the faq.

This is a community for professionals; there is an expectation that you work in this field.
Imagine a website for practicing doctors to ask other physicians for help with a tricky medical problem. I believe that a site like that would be very useful. But if a bunch of kids started asking, "How do I get into med school?", all of the practicing doctors would get fed-up and leave. And then no one would be around to answer the tricky medical problems.
So, from the first days that Quant.SE was created, the initial members decided that we would not allow non-quants to post on here. We don't prevent anyone from reading the material, nor do we demand credentials from first-time posters. But there is an expectation that anyone who participates must be a professional in this field. Your question history is far from that.

Doesn't https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/55249 look like a question like "How do I get into med school?" And I never asked such a question for Quantitative Finance. My question more likens to a medical student or resident choosing which specialty.

"Your question history is far from that." I'm uncertain if this is friendly?
